# SQLiteDatabase vs File storage

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to store structure type data (i.e. information of call logs like name, number, type of number, date, time, duration). Which is the best way and which is faster? SQLiteDatabase (make table and insert, delete logs in it) or use file storage (means make one class for all parameters and write their objects in file using input/output Stream and serializable) or the another way i heard about it is XML parser but i don't know this.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

If your goal is speed, the SQLite will give you a serious run for your money (especially if you wrap multiple inserts into transactions). SQLite has been optimized for everything you mentioned and it would be very easy to leverage the speed it can give you.

If portability is your goal, then files may be a slight bit easier. Files can be moved back and forth very easily easily, whereas SQLite might take some more effort.

If being able to search is your goal, then you'd be a fool not to use SQLite, as it is extremely good at searching and filtering results.

Comment: Thanks. but give me your suggestion. For now my goal is to store only 20 missed, dialed, received call logs. Then which you prefer? and if it is SQLite then please give some reason why file operation is not preferred?

Comment: @Dep...dude--I can't make a decision for you. I can tell you the ups and downs of both, but *you* have to decide what *you* want to write. Figure out what you need to do, and pick the method that does it best. Both methods will work, so figure out which one will be easier for *you*.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a very informed answer here because I'm just as new to the subject as you are, but here is the link from the developers page that goes over the different types of data storage. I hope you find it useful. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally, given you know the basics of Databases I would use a sqlite database. It's pretty straight forward in Android. In terms of speed I don't know which is faster, but if you don't have millions of datasets it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience in most cases **JSON in a file** is enough (mostly you need to store an array or an object or just a single number or string). I rarely need **SQLite** (which needs more time for setting it up and using it).